# Get Base64 code form IMG tag in IE browser

Tags: angular, image, typescript, base64

Need to get Base64 from static img html element.

Code

```
<img id="imgDownload" src="path to image"/>
var data = btoa(document.getElementById("imgDownload"))
```

But **btoa** is showing compile error. Have send the base64 encoded code to server to download the image.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150289/how-to-convert-image-into-base64-string-using-javascript

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert image into base64 string using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150289/how-to-convert-image-into-base64-string-using-javascript)

Comment: how to load image on canvas???

Comment: in IE on executing canvas.toDataURL("image/png"); it throwing error as "SecurityError"

Answer (score 0):

The value of `data` in

`var data = btoa(document.getElementById("imgDownload"))`

is

`W29iamVjdCBIVE1MSW1hZ2VFbGVtZW50XQ==`

which when you decode it is: `[object HTMLImageElement]`.

That's not what you want to send, I assume.

You might want: `var data = btoa(document.getElementById("imgDownload").src)` if you're after the URL.

If you're after the actual image bits, then you'll need to download the image - as someone else commented, that can be found here: [How to convert image into base64 string using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150289/how-to-convert-image-into-base64-string-using-javascript)